# Port forwarding with 2 routers

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have a simple 2 router setup. I'm using the second router as a switch and for wireless. The first router is forwarding a few ports (80, 443, 1433) on to a computer with a reserved I.P. address 192.168.1.15.

```
Verizon FiOS router, LAN port 1 -> Netgear WNR3500, LAN port 1 -> Devices
                    192.168.1.1 ->                 192.168.1.2 -> 192.168.1.x
```

Is it possible to have the the first router forward those ports to the second router, and then have the second router forward them on to the desired computer?  If so, is this a more secure or better way to handle it?

Basically, I just want know what the best configuration is if I am using 2 routers. Or, does it even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just set up the port forwarding for the range of ports and send them to the `WNR3500` - or if you want to forward **everything** you could set up a DMZ on your FiOS router to point to the `WNR3500`.

Not being familar with either of the devices, I can't give you any more specific details on how to actually execute that setup.

> is this a more secure or better way to
>   handle it

Not really. You're going to have headaches as soon as something goes wrong because you've got additional points of failure or places for the config to be messed up. I notice that they're all on the same subnet, so there's no real reason you would want to do this, unless the `WNR3500` offers some features not avaliable on the edge router.